# Vector field linearity

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Assuming I have a vector field, whose output is given by:

$$ \vec v = f\left( \vec x \right) $$

Where the function f is not necessarily linear, I have been asked to show that if I apply a coordinate transformation to the input vector:

$$ \vec x’ = A \vec x $$

Then the output vector also has the relationship:

$$ \vec v’ = A \vec x’ $$

I thought it would be a problem of linearity in $\vec x$, but I don’t really know where to start to prove this. It also seems like a strange result:

[image: enter preformatted text here]

I thought it would be good to post the problem in its original form as I may just be misinterpreting it:

[image]

### Edit: Explanation picture

From the comments it seems that:

[image]

Comment: Are $\vec x$ and $\vec v$ elements of the same space, or at least isomorphic spaces?

Comment: If I am understanding the question right, then this can't be right because if we let $A$ be multiplication by any scalar, then this is saying that $f(Ax) = f(\lambda\cdot x) = \lambda\cdot f(x)$ is almost requiring that $f$ be linear.

Comment: This is a physics thing (and @amd yes, the vector field has the same dimension as the space, or is at least embeddable). Say we're in two dimensions and $v((1,0)) = (0,1).$ Then we rotate the coordinate axes 90 degrees clockwise so that the point $(1,0)$ is now $(0,1)$ (note that from our new perspective the point appears to be 90 degrees *counter*clockwise from where it was). Now we want to describe the same "physical" configuration of vectors in our new coordinate system. Note that the vector pointed up before, and now points to the left... it has been rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise.

Comment: Yes, I came to the same conclusion; I thought that it must imply that f is linear. But I'm not so sure about it. If x and v are in the same space, then this is obvious; but I guess the question doesn't make this too clear.

Comment: This has nothing to do with linearity of $\vec v...$ it can be quite arbitrary. The key thing mathematically speaking is it's interpreted geometrically as a tangent vector field of $\mathbb R^n.$ Coordinate bases are described by partial derivatives wrt coordinates, thus a natural connection between coordinate transformation and change of basis of the vector field. cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_basis

Comment: I'm still not so sure how I'd answer this question though. A vector field assigns an output vector (of the same dimension) to an input vector. I've understood the relationship between coordinate bases and partial derivatives, but I don't understand how that helps me here. Why should a transformation of the original basis transform the vector field in the same way?

Comment: @user2662833 (you gotta @ me so I get pinged). I think my first explanation would be much more helpful than the second. Here's another: Draw a coordinate axes and some vectors at various points on the plane. Now walk over to your favorite one. draw a translated axes at its point. What are the vector's components? They are the coordinates of  the head of the vector in that little coordinate system you drew. Now we perform a passive coordinate transformation (draw some new axes but don't change the vectors).  Now repeat what I said from "Now walk ... you drew." See how the components changed?

Comment: Sorry @spaceisdarkgreen I pinged you this time :D :P. Thanks for that, so for clarity what you’re saying is that we measure the vector field using the same basis vectors that the space is in (see my picture). Under that assumption, it would make sense that this result would be true. I suppose that even if we didn’t measure it with these particular basis vectors (i and j), applying a linear transform to the input space would apply the same transform to the translated axis. I don’t know if this amounts to a proof, but intuitively it makes much more sense. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @user2662833 gotta be careful what I wish for :). No, it looks like you understood what I was saying.

Comment: lol :P I appreciate the help!